# apt returns "E: Unmet dependencies" when I try to install a package, how can I diagnose the issue and find out why it occurs?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install a package, but the package manager (`apt-get`, software center, etc.) refuses to install it due unmet dependencies.

Are my attempts to install the package causing the dependencies issue? How can I tell what the issue is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are installing an specific package/program and you hit a dependency issue there are two causes:

- Your dependencies were already broken.
- It isn't possible to install the package you want due to your current setup.

---

The first case is easy to figure out. Just execute `sudo apt-get check`. This will report you any problem with the already installed packages and you will know how to solve them.

```
sudo apt-get check                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpurple-dev : Depends: libpurple0 (>= 2.10.9) but it is not installed
                 Depends: libpurple0 (< 2.10.9+1~) but it is not installed
 pidgin : Depends: libpurple0 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
 pidgin-whatsapp : Depends: libpurple0 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Normally if you didn't install any packages manually with `dpkg`, you have missing mirrors, broken PPA's or a mix of different version repositories (like Debian's and Ubuntu's or Precise and Saucy) this could be fixed with a simple `sudo apt-get -f install`. If that doesn't fix it, you may need to ask for help adding all the results of the operations you attempted plus the output of `apt-cache policy` for all relevant packages:

```
apt-cache policy pidgin-whatsapp pidgin libpurple-dev libpurple0
```

Now, if that results clean and the dependency issue only happens when you try to install a package, you may need to know why apt is refusing to install the package. This is tiring to do and would pose a hurdle if you want to solve your issue fast, and each problem has it's own solution. Is recommended in such cases using `aptitude`. First we install it:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Now you will ask aptitude why you can not install the package using:

```
aptitude why-not package
```

It will show you a nice list telling you why the package can't not be installed. It could be a missing package, that depends on a package that isn't available, or some other package that has conflicts/breaks it. Example:

```
aptitude why-not lsb-core:amd64
i   lsb-security Recommends lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian12)
i A lsb-core     Conflicts  lsb-core:amd64
```

In this case, I have installed lsb-security package, which installed lsb-core 32-bits version, and doesn't allow me to install the 64-bit version.

Comment: ah `aptitude` again.. needn't that be preinstalled in your system? How can you be sure most of the solution seekers would have the tool installed previously? (but if it was, yes that would give an easy way.. then even better option IMO would be to have Synaptic Package Manager, great graphical software, helps solve broken packages in some clicks, and other services given by apt being its front-end)..

Comment: you can use this as awareness Q&A to get people have _Synaptic Package Manager_ and _Aptitude_ to make life easier.. :) (I was disappointed to not having Synaptic shipped as a default package.)

Comment: @rusty Synaptic isn't installed by default either :/